# NextJS build not pre-rendering the index.js page as a static page

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a NextJS app (Next JS 13.2.3) that has a login screen component on the index.js page. It contains user/password field , a login button and an image. The index.js file is inside the pages folder.
When I go to build the app , using next build,  the index.js page does not appear anywhere in the list of pages built , that show which are static and which are SSG.

The index.js page does not fetch external data , there is no getStaticProps, or getStaticPaths or getServerSideProps.  It just has handlers that authenticate using an auth library and then navigate to another page using router.push.

My question is , shouldn't this page be a statically generated page and be rendered immediately without any delay when first navigating to it on the browser ? Instead it takes a good 5+ seconds for it to be rendered,  seemingly being generated on demand. The successive refreshes are very fast, but the first time is sloooow.
By contrast, another app using pure React hosted on the same platform, renders the login page immediately with no delay. Seems upside down.

My understanding based on nextjs doc (https://nextjs.org/learn-pages-router/basics/data-fetching/pre-rendering) , is that by default nextjs pre-renders and generates html for each page in advance at build time. But the index.js page does not show up in the build artifacts as being statically generated.
If I disable javascript on the browser the page does not render at all (white blank screen). I would imagine that a statically generated html would display , but any interactivity would be disabled if no javascript. But it does not render at all.

Am I doing anything wrong ?

The component returned by the index.js page is :

```
return (
    <>
    <Head>
        <title>Customer Data</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Metric data for customer" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    </Head>
    <main className={styles.mainContainer}>
        <div className={styles.imageContainer}></div>
        <div className={styles.formContainer}>
            <div>
                <h5 className={orbitron.className}>Customer Portal</h5>
            </div>
            {query?.p === 'signup'
               ? <SignUp showSignupPage={showSignupPage}/>
               : <SignIn handleFederatedLogin={handleFederatedLogin}/>
            }
        </div>
    </main>
    </>
)
```

The nextjs app is hosted on AWS Amplify.

[image: Build using next build]